# What does BatteryStatus isCharging gives back?

Tags: java, android

If you run this code, what does `isCharging` give back when it's charging and when it's full?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                         status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried *running* it?

Answer (score 3):

`isCharging` will be `true` if either of those conditions are met.